# Corousel Slider issue only accept 5 values from firebase booklist in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

*Need to adjust list in a way to accept 1 image if there is one
to accept 2 image if there are two and so on by checking and not in the range
of 0-4 images in corousel slider as it shown in the code. Please help basically list images data comes from firebase. Thank you for the time. Here is the code for the carousel slider shown below
.*

**Code:**

```
class _CarouselState extends State<Carousel> {
  int activeIndex = 0;
  OrderController orderController = Get.find(tag: 'orderController');
  BookController bookController = Get.find(tag: 'bookController');
  RxList<dynamic> bookList = [].obs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    bookList = bookController.getSpecifiedBooks(Constants.onSaleConst);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => bookList.isNotEmpty
          ? Column(children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: 220.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                        autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                            const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        viewportFraction: 0.95,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) =>
                            (setState(() => {activeIndex = index}))),
                    //TODO: need to define data type of item(in map) to Book to avoid possibilities of future error
                    items: bookList
                        .getRange(0,
                            5) //this is hardcoded to 6 elements from discounted books list
                        .map((item) => Stack(children: [
//  CachedNetworkImage(
//       key: widget.key,
//       imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
//       placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
//       errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
//     )

                              Image.network(item.coverImage, loadingBuilder:
                                  (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                                      ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                                if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                  return child;
                                }
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        value: loadingProgress
                                                    .expectedTotalBytes !=
                                                null
                                            ? loadingProgress
                                                    .cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                                loadingProgress
                                                    .expectedTotalBytes!
                                            : null,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1500),

              )
            ])
          : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying get all data ?

Comment: not 50 if there are 50 images just work with even 1 image or 2 come in the list.

Comment: ok you like to set the limit up to 5 image?

Comment: any images from 1 to 5 currently it gives range error if its less than 4 images

Comment: Try below logic,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to check if the list size getter than you are trying to access using `getRange`
Change the logic like

```dart
items: bookList.getRange(0, bookList.length<5?bookList.length:5).map(...)
```

Here it will provide maximum 5 item.